# How to update multiple row with different ID in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is from the last question that I asked..

I have a membership table

```
Schema::create('role_memberships', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('role_id');
        $table->string('MembershipName');
        $table->text('MembershipValue');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I have two rows data with same role_id and I want to update two rows
This is my controller

```
$updateArray = [['MembershipValue' => $request->PostAdMaxImage], 
['MembershipValue' => $request->PostAdExpiredDay]];
DB::table('role_memberships')->where('role_id', $id)-
>whereIn('role_id', $role->pluck('id'))->update($updateArray);
```

when I tried to update, I got an error array to string conversion..

Comment: can you post your error? and $role->pluck('id') return array because whereIn wnat an array as 2 parameters. ex (->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3]))

Comment: @LorenzoBerti I do update with using ajax.. so, the error only displayed in inspect element

Comment: `foreach($updateArray as $array){
        DB::table('role_memberships')->where('role_id', $id)->whereIn('role_id', $role->pluck('id'))->update($array);
}`

Comment: @SamuelJames I have used the way like you give, but the problem is my data have the same value.. 
example: `id = 1, role_id = 1, I do $request->PostAdMaxImage  = 'hello'` 
`id = 2, role_id = 1, I do $request->PostAdExpiredDay = 'world'`.
then, I save and re-open again.. my value of PostAdMaxImage and PostAdExpiredDay  turn into 'world', in the other word, it only take the last value

Comment: Please note that you're writting names differently (MembershipValue will be converted into membershipvalue in the database, try to use the same pattern for both being readable code, something like membership_value, and case sensitive (In the future, you can have a need for that type of word and you'll know by searching in the files if the name is referring to a datatable or some value).

Comment: Take a look at my answer below, the issue is on your $updateArray.

Comment: @abr How can I write the names differently? MembershipValue is my column header's name..

Comment: What I'm saying is merely my opinion. In your database, the column name will be 'membershipvalue'. What I'm talking about is semantics, e.g. think you'll stop writing code on this project now and in 1 year you'll want to re-evaluate your database, or need to make a change. membership_value is a lot more readable than membershipvalue or membershipname

Comment: @abr oh i see.. thankyou for the feedback ;)

Comment: have you been able to find a solution?

Comment: @abr I have found it and I have posted the solution too.. But if you have the shortest way, you can share in here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is only the way that I can used..

```
DB::table('role_memberships')->where('role_id', $id)->where('MembershipName','PostAdMaxImage')->update(['MembershipValue' => $request->PostAdMaxImage]);
DB::table('role_memberships')->where('role_id', $id)->where('MembershipName','PostAdExpiredDay')->update(['MembershipValue' => $request->PostAdExpiredDay]);
```

If you guys has the best way or the shortest way, please let me know.. thankyou ;)

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE BATCH (BULK) IN LARAVEL

https://github.com/mavinoo/updateBatch

```
$table = 'users';

$value = [
      [
          'id' => 1,
          'status' => 'active'
      ],
      [
          'id' => 5,
          'status' => 'deactive',
          'nickname' => 'Ghanbari'
     ],
     [
          'id' => 10,
          'status' => 'active',
         'date' => Carbon::now()
     ],
     [
         'id' => 11,
         'username' => 'mavinoo'
     ]
];

$index = 'id';

UpdateBatch::updateBatch($table, $value, $index);
```

Answer (score 5):

It works for me, even if the thread is 2 years ago I would like to share my solution too, I hope this can help somebody.

In blade

```
<input name="quantity[]">
<input name="total[]">
<input name="prodId[]">
```

Controller

```
foreach ($request->prodId as $key => $value) {
      $data = array(                 
          'quantity'=>$request->quantity[$key],
          'total'=>$request->total[$key],                   
      );         
      Cart::where('id',$request->prodId[$key])
      ->update($data); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 error:

1) The whereIn function want an array for parameter as

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
                ->get();
```

2) The update function want an simple array for parameter like

```
DB::table('users')
            ->where('id', 1)
            ->update(['votes' => 1]);
```

You ar passing an `[[], []]`

So you have to pass example `$model->update(['MembershipValue' => $request->PostAdMaxImage])`

here you found the complete documentation for `update` and `whereIn` https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries

Comment: when I do return `DB::table('role_memberships')->where('role_id', $id)->whereIn('role_id', $role->pluck('id'))->get();`
It return membership data with id = 1 and id = 2

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the `upsert()` method given from Laravel eloquent model, its a multiple update or create method, you can just simply pass the needed data in an array with the ids of each column and specify the unique column last set the columns that needs to be updated and you will obtain the result you are looking
for.

for more information read the docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. it works to me .

```
  DB::table('role_memberships')->where('role_id', $id)-
>update(['MembershipValue' => $request->PostAdMaxImage, 'MembershipValue' => $request->PostAdExpiredDay]);
```

Comment: this does not work for me.. I have tried the way like this.. and the result still same, it take the last record.. But I don't understand, the response in inspect element show like this 
`[{"id":2,"RoleName":"zxdas","IsAllCategory":false,"IsUserCanLogin":false,"created_at":"2017-10-19 14:55:46","updated_at":"2017-10-19 14:55:46"},[{"role_id":"2","MembershipName":"PostAdMaxImage","MembershipValue":"hello"},{"role_id":"2","MembershipName":"PostAdExpiredDay","MembershipValue":"world"}]]`

Comment: I think you have a problem in checking the role id, do you check this variable "$id"? try to remove the "whereIn('role_id', $role->pluck('id'))" in query

check agan the query .

Answer (score 0):

> I have two rows data with same role_id and I want to update two rows This is my controller

```
$updateArray = [['MembershipValue' => $request->PostAdMaxImage], MembershipValue' => $request->PostAdExpiredDay]];
DB::table('role_memberships')->where('role_id', $id)->whereIn('role_id', $role->pluck('id'))->update($updateArray);
```

> when I tried to update, I got an error array to string conversion..

That is because you have an array within an array on your $updateArray. Fixing it like this should correct your error:

```
$updateArray = ['MembershipValue' => $request->PostAdMaxImage, 'MembershipValue' => $request->PostAdExpiredDay];
```